# Is there a panel I can use in WPF that will "defeat" SizeToContent?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, panel, sizetocontent

I basically want certain parts of my window to not affect SizeToContent (things like a title bar) so that it appears to have no size and collapses. Is there a panel I can use to do this (like a ScrollViewer maybe?) or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a control that will return (0,0) from [MeasureOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride.aspx).  [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) will do this, but it may not have other behavior you want.  You could also subclass an existing panel, like Grid, and just return an empty size:

```
public class ZeroGrid
    : Grid
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        return new Size();
    }
}
```

That will behave like a Grid, so its content will stretch to its actual size, but it will always have a DesiredSize of zero so it won't affect SizeToContent.